# "subject + de + être"? ("Tu de l'est encore plus"); gemination (consonant sound repeated twice) confusing auto-generated subtitles

Tags: grammaire

*EDIT: After reading an answer that explained why I had difficulty with the subtitles, I'm editing my question's title so that it's more useful to people when they search French.SE, so that they can find the useful information about gemination in the answer.*

---

In [this](https://youtu.be/QNK8W94k8rw?t=12) youtube video, in the first fifteen seconds, the auto-generated subtitles give:

> Ça a été sans aucun doute leur sujet des derniers mois, les pitbulls.
> Dans le coin droit, on trouve des gens qui les aiment tellement qu'ils
> sont prêts menacé de mort ceux qui s'y opposent. Parce que la
> meilleure façon de convaincre les gens que ton chien pas dangereux,
> c'est de leur montrer que toi, **tu de l'est encore plus**.

I'm having trouble understanding "tu de l'est encore plus".

Some thoughts I have when trying to understand this:

1. I can't figure out what the **l'** replacing?
2. If I try to make the clause simpler, I might try to remove the *l'*. Then I get "tu d'*est* encore", instead of the *es* that I would expect (as in, "tu d'*es* encore"). So it seems that the "tu" has no conjugated verb attached to it; but it seems that the "tu" does require a conjugated verb -- where it is!?
3. Perhaps the auto-generated subtitles meant "tu es" instead of the "tu est" that they gave. I still have never seen a construction like "Tu d'es + encore plus" or "Je de suis + encore plus" before.

Questions:

1. Can you help me understand the structure of "Tu de l'est encore plus", and its meaning? What is the **l'** replacing?
2. Can you give me other example sentences with the same or a similar structure?

Comment: Mon oreille formée au français hexagonal entend « toi, tu l'es encore ». Je pense que la façon dont les Québécois prononce le son d'attaque [l], de façon beaucoup plus dure qu'en France, fait que tu entends ce qui te parait un [d] qui s’introduirait avant le [l]. « L' » est un pronom personnel qui remplace  « être dangereux ». There are more mistakes in the transcript : "...prêts **à menacer** de mort..." and ".. convaincre les gens que ton chien **est** pas dangereux..". Proper grammar should be * **n'est** pas dangereux*, lots of people just drop the **ne** but **est** must be there.

Comment: @None This is a good warning to me, now, that Youtube's auto-generated subtitles aren't  trustworthy, and that if I am confused when following them, maybe it's the transcript that is wrong! (I rely heavily on subtitles; my ears still cannot follow spoken French, whether it's Québecois French or Standard French)

Comment: Never trust youtube's auto-generated subtitles! You will find that movies are a better way to train your ear, with the subtitles in the foreign language as well. There can be mistakes but very few, they're more approximations due to the human transcriber than real mistakes. Yes, French is a very difficult language to understand because it not pronounced as it is written! Mind you, same with English!

Comment: Most movies actually have the closed captions in good French since they just reproduce what is said (most of the time) and are based on the scripts. So unless an actor says something slightly different, they are accurate.  I have never seen "auto-generated" closed captions. That said, anything auto-generated for speech will have mistakes in any language. I suggest you watch movies or series in French with the closed captions turned on.

Comment: @Lambie The only reason I think that my French is improving at all, is that I've been watching Quebecois TV during the pandemic, which (on official websites -- not youtube) has word-for-word subtitles. I don't think I could learn languages in the pre-Internet era, without media to watch, tbh

Comment: Do not confuse sub-titles (which are usually understood to mean translations) with closed captions, which means a reproduction of a text in the language of the film or series or broadcast. Do you understand the difference now?

Comment: @Lambie Rest assured, I watch the Québecois TV with word-for-word captions/subtitles whenever I can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person definitely says:

> Toi, **tu l'es** encore plus.

You tube has been confused because the ***L*** is geminated, i.e. pronounced twice, one after ***tu*** and the second one in ***l'es***:

/twa tylle ɑ̃kɔʁ plys/

This particular duplication of a consonant is not Québec French specific. It might also be heard in Paris area and other francophone regions, possibly more often in careful speech in my opinion although some studies seem to tell it's more related to the *français populaire*.

*Gemination* is standard in the third person singular ***il l'est*** and ***elle l'est*** and allows to distinguish these forms from ***il est*** and ***elle est***. I believe this regular gemination somewhat influenced the way the first and second persons are pronounced, despite the lack of ambiguity between ***j'ai*** / ***je l'ai*** and ***tu as*** / ***tu l'as***.

You can read [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01859307) the abstract of a paper about this phenomenon called *gémination des proclitiques*.

Comment: @Lambie Not at all.  The recommendation is to answer in French to a question asked in French and in English to a question asked in English. You can of course also answer in your native language if you are not comfortable with the language used in the question. What doesn't make sense is to reply in French to a question asked in English when your own language is also English. When an answer is made in the "wrong" language by mistake, the best practice is to edit your answer with the translation in the other language. Thanks for asking.